# Custom object to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I would like to add a custom object to NSDictionary. It should store three variables: two strings and a boolean.

I read around the net and found NSCoder to be the way but I dislike the result. By using [dictionary setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:customObject]] I end up with NSData information instead of human readable text. My target is to make it readable for human eyes. I do not want to encode the object into binary data.

To make it a little bit more complicated I would like to add my objects inside NSArray. For testing purposes I tried to add NSStrings to NSArray and to invoke [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"myKey"]. The result is perfect. It is readable for human. I would like to add my custom object instead of the NSString.

Desired result should look something like this:

```
{
   TextStrokeColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.5 1";
   TextStrokeWidth = 0;
   MyObjects = (
        MyCustomObject = { 
             name = "name";
             boooool = 0;
             description = "";
        }
        , ... other objects );
}
```

What should I use? I do not really get the difference and the use for NSCoder, NSCoding, NSCopying.

I need to be able to edit the text file later on the disk. By having binary representation I cannot. But seems there is no straightforward method.

Comment: Why do you need to archive the custom object? Are you writing it to disk? Why not use another dictionary?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "using another dictionary"?

Comment: you can have an array of dictionaries (with specific keys) in your dictionary

Comment: Actually this is what I am looking for. Sort of. Should I fill up the array manually with NSDictionary elements created by the custom object and to implement a new initWithDictionary: to load it back if necessary?

Comment: You haven't told us what the actual usage / problem is, we're just talking about an abstract concept, either solution will do in this case. Indeed your 'human readable' part seems to have little impact as it's a function of logging the content out and that can still be done by unarchiving

Comment: In fact I would like to store the information inside a file and later to read it back. The main goal is to add predefined templates to the application. The idea is to store the information inside an NSDictionary structure. It is easy to maintain and customize later. Then the app reads back the text file and loads different templates.

Comment: So your original code with the archiving enables that, so this issue is just that when you log the container dictionary you get a binary representation? In that case, store the raw object and archive the entire container dictionary into a file. Binary on disk, not in memory.

Comment: The whole point is to be able to edit the text file later on the disk. By having binary representation I cannot. But seems there is no straightforward method.

Comment: Ok, so that is the key piece of information missing from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use arrays, dictionaries, strings, numbers, dates (anything which can be written into a plist or JSON).

The question is wether this is done solely during 'archiving', or whether your in-memory representation is also arrays and dictionaries. You can also create a custom class which either uses a dictionary internally to store the data and archives / reloads from that dictionary, or the custom class is a standard class with properties and creates a dictionary on-the-fly when archiving or reloading.

Note that when using a keyed archiver, it can support setting the `outputFormat` to `NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0` for some use cases, so once your custom class implements archiving to plist data types you can easily archive the container to a plist (JSON will require more leg work from you to collate the data into true containers).

Comment: I think we are getting closer to the point. I use NSDictionary and NSArray everywhere around the application. Is it NSPropertyListSerialization to look after?

Comment: If you just use arrays and dictionaries with the other data types supported by plists then you can use `NSPropertyListSerialization`, if you use any custom classes then you need to do something else to convert into a valid format before archiving to disk

Comment: Just to give you a feedback. Finally I use NSJSONSerialization. I had to implement certain NSDictionary to MyCustomObject conversion. But works well, readable, editable so I met the target.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried actually creating a custom object by just making a class?

```
@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BOOL boolValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;

@end

@implementation MyCustomClass
// put any implementation methods here
@end
```

Then you can add it to an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary` as you would with any other class.

```
MyCustomClass *myObject = [MyCustomClass new];
myObject.name = @"name";
myObject.boolValue = YES;
myObject.description @"a description";

[myMutableArray addObject:myObject];
myMutableDictionary[@"some key"] = myObject;
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrog but using this solution myMutableDictionary[@"some key"] = myObject will be a pointer to my object inside myMutableDictionary.

Comment: The pointers added to `myMutableDictionary` and `myMutableArray` will both point to the same object that the pointer `myObject` points to. What are you actually asking?

Comment: If you look to the question this is not what I am looking for. I need to have a Dictionary that contains readable key-value pairs describing my custom object.